# Element not found in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search

I know there are similar topics and I checked every single one but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

I have a list (todos) and want to search for an ID with the following function:

```
def searchID():
    todo_id_search = input('Please input ID:')
    if todo_id_search in todos:
        print(todo_id_search)
    else:
        print("ID not in list")
```

Somehow it never returns the ID (even though its in the list). Should be possible to search for the ID like that or ma I thinking wrong? I'm using Python 3.7.

Thanks!

Comment: You should include a language tag (probably [tag:python])

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions about a particular piece of code can best be answered when there is enough of it for us to copy, run, and get your current result: a [mcve]. Then we can offer fixes. So. What is in `todos`?

Comment: The underlying problem was probably something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427, but the question as asked is not suitable for the site as it does not contain any of the necessary information to debug the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is caused due to the `datatype` mismatch between your `input` data and elements of the list that you are checking with.

for example: if the elements of list in your `todos` are `integer` data, then

```
todo_id_search = input('Please input ID:')
```

this `todo_id_search` is always a `string` as `input` always returns `string` type data hence failing your `if` block of code as `string` and `int` cannot be compared,For troubleshooting you can check its type by using

```
print (type(todo_id_search))
```

and after confirming your list `todos` elements type you can perform the necessary type casting in user input data i.e `todo_id_search`, by using `int(todo_id_search)` or `float(todo_id_search)` in your `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks - I was blind. Changed to str(todo_id_search) and everything works now.